# track data that leaves the phone

Tags: android, security

Is there any way an app can track any data that leaves the phone (or maybe enters too?)?

Unless there is an Android OS feature that I don't know about, I'm wondering if there is any way a program can catch any data that leaves the phone and display it to the user of the phone.

If we could do this we could catch those apps that steal our data for their own purposes.  I know that when, for instance, my app does an HTTP Post, the data goes out some port.  I have written broadcast receivers that catches some kinds of data coming in but I would like to catch all data going out.
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to write your own VPN implementation. If the user sets that up on their device, the VPN implementation will have access to all packets going across that VPN connection.

> If we could do this we could catch those apps that steal our data for their own purposes

By that same token, you want to steal **all** the data. Not surprisingly, this is not easy to do, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is essentially packet sniff on your Android device. There are a number of options to do this. You can use an app like ProxyDroid to tunnel all your phone traffic through.  Another option is tPacketCapture which uses a VPN pass through (beware of your private info going to a third party!!!) and Shark for Root which is a traffic sniffer that works on 3G and Wifi.